# Derive a method for approximating $f'''(x_0)$ whose error term is of order $h^2$ by expanding the function $f$ in a fourth Taylor polynomial

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

This is a Numerical Analysis textbook question on Numerical Differentiation (like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation)

(fyi, I asked a similar but different question on the same textbook section earlier. This is the last one, promise :) )

### Official Textbook Question

Derive a method for approximating $f'''(x_0)$ whose error term is of order $h^2$ by expanding the function $f$ in a fourth Taylor polynomial about $x_0$ and evaluating at $x_0 \pm h$ and $x_0 \pm 2h$

### My Question

I believe I can do this problem, but I end up with an error term that has a $h^4$ term while the question asks for a solution with an error term of order $h^2$. Is this right, am I doing something wrong?

### My Work

First basic four term Taylor expansion and remainder term:

\begin{align*}
  f(x) &= f(x_0) + \frac{f'(x_0)}{1!} (x - x_0) + \frac{f''(x_0)}{2!} (x - x_0)^2 + \frac{f'''(x_0)}{3!} (x - x_0)^3 + \frac{f''''(\xi(x))}{4!} (x - x_0)^4 \\
  f(x) &= f(x_0) + f'(x_0) (x - x_0) + \frac{1}{2} f''(x_0) (x - x_0)^2 + \frac{1}{6} f'''(x_0) (x - x_0)^3 + \frac{1}{24} f''''(\xi(x)) (x - x_0)^4 \\
\end{align*}

Apply for $x_0 \pm h, x_0 \pm 2h$:

\begin{align*}
  f(x_0 - 2h) &= f(x_0) - 2 f'(x_0) h + 2 f''(x_0) h^2 - \frac{4}{3} f'''(x_0) h^3 + \frac{2}{3} f''''(\xi(x_0 - 2h)) h^4 \\
  f(x_0 - h) &= f(x_0) - f'(x_0) h + \frac{1}{2} f''(x_0) h^2 - \frac{1}{6} f'''(x_0) h^3 + \frac{1}{24} f''''(\xi(x_0 - h)) h^4 \\
  f(x_0 + h) &= f(x_0) + f'(x_0) h + \frac{1}{2} f''(x_0) h^2 + \frac{1}{6} f'''(x_0) h^3 + \frac{1}{24} f''''(\xi(x_0 + h)) h^4 \\
  f(x_0 + 2h) &= f(x_0) + 2 f'(x_0) h + 2 f''(x_0) h^2 + \frac{4}{3} f'''(x_0) h^3 + \frac{2}{3} f''''(\xi(x_0 + 2h)) h^4 \\
\end{align*}

Dropping the remainder terms and converting to matrix form:

\begin{align*}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -2 & 2 & -\frac{4}{3} \\
    1 & -1 & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{6} \\
    1 & 1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{6} \\
    1 & 2 & 2 & \frac{4}{3} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    f(x_0) \\
    h \cdot f'(x_0) \\
    h^2 \cdot f''(x_0) \\
    h^3 \cdot f'''(x_0) \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  &\approx
  \begin{bmatrix}
    f(x_0 - 2h) \\
    f(x_0 - h) \\
    f(x_0 + h) \\
    f(x_0 + 2h) \\
  \end{bmatrix} \\
\end{align*}

Inverting the matrix:

Wolfram Alpha

```
inverse {{1, -2, 2, -4/3}, {1, -1, 1/2, -1/6}, {1, 1, 1/2, 1/6}, {1, 2, 2, 4/3}}
```

\begin{align*}
  \begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{1}{6} & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & -\frac{1}{6} \\
\frac{1}{12} & -\frac{2}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & -\frac{1}{12} \\
\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
-\frac{1}{2} & 1 & -1 & \frac{1}{2} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
f(x_0 - 2h) \\
f(x_0 - h) \\
f(x_0 + h) \\
f(x_0 + 2h) \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  &\approx
  \begin{bmatrix}
f(x_0) \\
h \cdot f'(x_0) \\
h^2 \cdot f''(x_0) \\
h^3 \cdot f'''(x_0) \\
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

This gives us:

\begin{align*}
  f'''(x_0) &\approx \frac{1}{h^3} \left[ -\frac{1}{2} f(x_0 - 2h) + f(x_0 - h) - f(x_0 + h) + \frac{1}{2} f(x_0 + 2h) \right] \\
\end{align*}

This gives an error term of:

\begin{align*}
  h \left[ -\frac{1}{3} f''''(\xi(x_0 - 2h))
          + \frac{1}{24} f''''(\xi(x_0 - h))
          - \frac{1}{24} f''''(\xi(x_0 + h))
          + \frac{1}{3} f''''(\xi(x_0 + 2h)) \right] \\
\end{align*}

Is this wrong because my error term has $h$ instead of $h^2$?

*UPDATE*: Fixed issue where I was off by a factor of $h^3$

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1301769/approximation-formula-for-third-derivative-is-my-approach-right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing something in establishing your system. In extracting the rational constants, the powers of $h$ are still bound to the derivatives, thus the system has to be
\begin{align*}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -2 & 2 & -\frac{4}{3} \\
    1 & -1 & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{6} \\
    1 & 1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{6} \\
    1 & 2 & 2 & \frac{4}{3} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    f(x_0) \\
    f'(x_0)h \\
    f''(x_0)h^2 \\
    f'''(x_0)h^3 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  &\approx
  \begin{bmatrix}
    f(x_0 - 2h) \\
    f(x_0 - h) \\
    f(x_0 + h) \\
    f(x_0 + 2h) \\
  \end{bmatrix} \\
\end{align*}
with the solution formula
\begin{align*}
  \begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{1}{6} & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & -\frac{1}{6} \\
\frac{1}{12} & -\frac{2}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & -\frac{1}{12} \\
\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
-\frac{1}{2} & 1 & -1 & \frac{1}{2} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
f(x_0 - 2h) \\
f(x_0 - h) \\
f(x_0 + h) \\
f(x_0 + 2h) \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  &\approx
  \begin{bmatrix}
f(x_0) \\
f'(x_0)h \\
f''(x_0)h^2 \\
f'''(x_0)h^3 \\
  \end{bmatrix} \\
\end{align*}
You should also recognize that because of the symmetry, the coefficients of the 4th derivative cancel so that the error term for $f'''(x_0)h^3$ is $O(h^5)$. As you have to divide by $h^3$, the error term for $f'''(x_0)$ is $O(h^2)$.

---

You can greatly reduce the computations by recognizing the symmetry of the situation and start with the Taylor expansions of 
$$
f(x_0+kh)-f(x_0-kh)=2f'(x_0)kh+\frac13f'''(x_0)k^3h^3+\frac1{60}f^{(5)}(x_0)k^5h^5+O(h^7)
$$
so that you get for the coefficients $$2A_2+A_1=0\\8A_2+A_1=3$$

Comment: Thanks! I see that I erroneously dropped the $h^3$ term. I updated my main answer. Now the error term has $h$ not $h^2$. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, that is right. But as I said, the symmetric differences of the 4th derivatives are themselves $O(h)$ which combines with the factor to $O(h^2)$.